# How to add network throttling in lighthouse programatically as node module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lighthouse, web-performance

I want to add different network throttling conditions like slow 3g, fast 4g, etc to check the web vitals metrics scores like FCP, LCP, and TBT depending on different network conditions.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const chromeLauncher = require('chrome-launcher');
const HOME_PAGE_URL = 'http://localhost:4000';

(async () => {
  const chrome = await chromeLauncher.launch({ chromeFlags: ['--headless'] });
  const options = { logLevel: 'info', output: 'html', onlyCategories: ['performance'], port: chrome.port };
  const runnerResult = await lighthouse(HOME_PAGE_URL, options);

  // `.report` is the HTML report as a string
  const reportHtml = runnerResult.report;
  fs.writeFileSync('lhreport.html', reportHtml);

  // `.lhr` is the Lighthouse Result as a JS object
  console.log('Report is done for', runnerResult.lhr.finalDisplayedUrl);
  console.log('Performance score was', runnerResult.lhr.categories.performance.score * 100);

  await chrome.kill();
})();
```